# Null pointer error after declaring / initializing Java string buffer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a Null pointer exception for the StingBuffer .

Below is the sample code ..

```
StringBuffer buff = new StingBuffer(“dummy”+”dummy2”
+”dummy3”);
```

I get an null pointer at the first line where buff is initialized .

So I changed this to

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
buff.append(“dummy”
+”dummy1”
+”dummy2”);
```

Now I get the null pointer exception at buff.append line.
Which is right after its initialization and it is very strange.

I am going crazy as to why I am getting a null pointer exception when I have actually initialized it .

Can anyone advice on this !!!

Comment: From a first glance, your code looks correct. So please provide a REAL [mcve] that we can run to repro the problem, and include the stack trace in your question too.

Comment: And of course, study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it ... as sooner or later, your question will  almost inadvertently be closed as duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 2):

After copy/ pasting your code into an IDE it turns out that you are using the wrong String constant delimiter.
you are using  `”` instead of `"` .
This way the code should work correctly.

Comment: I was typing the sample using IPhone  . But the point is why would I get a null pointer exception when I have initialized it.  I dont want to share the exact code as it is company code.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange with `NPE`, whey you should get a *compile time error* because of `<br/>` and incorrect `”`. Check this out:

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
buff.append("dummy" + "dummy1" + "dummy2");
```